# Ember query api with multiple parameters

Tags: ember.js, store

I was wondering if it was possible to query the API with multiple parameters in one go.

I know we can do

```
this.store.find("assetType",{category:"ancillary"});
```

which will do a query of http://l5.dev/api/assetTypes?category=ancillary

But what I want to do is a query of 
 http://l5.dev/api/assetTypes?category=ancillary&channel=print

Is this possible to do this in Ember on one go. Or will I have to do a filter on the results of the first query instead?

Comment: Have you tried `this.store.find("assetType",{category:"ancillary", channel:"print"});` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like :

```
this.store.find("search",{category:"user", limit : 10});
```

This will generate GET request like

```
/search?category=user&limit=10
```